# Convert regex positive look ahead to sed operation

Tags: regex, sed, replace, match, positive-lookahead

I would like to sed to find and replace every occurrence of `-` with `_` but only before the first occurrence of `=` on every line.

Here is a dataset to work with:

```
ke-y_0-1="foo"
key_two="bar"
key_03-three="baz-jazz-mazz"
key-="rax_foo"
key-05-five="craz-"
```

In the end the dataset should look like this:

```
ke_y_0_1="foo"
key_two="bar"
key_03_three="baz-jazz-mazz"
key_="rax_foo"
key_05_five="craz-"
```

I found this regex will match properly.

```
\-(?=.*=)
```

However the regex uses positive lookaheads and it appears that `sed` (even with `-E`, `-e` or `-r`) dose not know how to work with positive lookaheads.

I tried the following but keep getting `Invalid preceding regular expression`

```
cat dataset.txt | sed -r "s/-(?=.*=)/_/g"
```

Is it possible to convert this in a usable way with sed?

Note, I do not want to use perl. However I am open to awk.

Comment: Curious why you don't want to use perl. In any case,  I have a blog post https://learnbyexample.github.io/sed-lookarounds/ if you want more examples and ways to implement lookaround in GNU sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed ':a;s/^\([^=]*\)-/\1_/;ta' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/CXgnEl):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='ke-y_0-1="foo"
key_two="bar"
key_03-three="baz-jazz-mazz"
key-="rax_foo"
key-05-five="craz-"'
sed ':a; s/^\([^=]*\)-/\1_/;ta' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
ke_y_0_1="foo"
key_two="bar"
key_03_three="baz-jazz-mazz"
key_="rax_foo"
key_05_five="craz-"
```

*Details*:

- `:a` - setting a label named `a`
- `s/^\([^=]*\)-/\1_/` - find any zero or more chars other than a `=` char from the start of string (while capturing into Group 1 (`\1`)) and then matches a `-` char, and replaces with Group 1 value (`\1`) and a `_` (that replaces the found `-` char)
- `ta` - jump to lable `a` location upon successful replacement. Else, stop.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the interesting solution and explanation!

Comment: Yes thank you again Wiktor, you always have good awk and sed solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

You might also use `awk` setting the field separator to `=` and replace all `-` with `_` for the first field.

To print only the replaced lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}gsub("-", "_", $1)' file
```

Output

```
ke_y_0_1="foo"
key_03_three="baz-jazz-mazz"
key_="rax_foo"
key_05_five="craz-"
```

If you want to print all lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}{gsub("-", "_", $1);print}' file
```